# navigationBarのbackButtonで戻った時にアクションを起こす方法

Tags: swift2, xcode7

こんにちは

現在私はページを遷移した先でNSTimerを起動するといったことをしているのですが、タイマーの作動中にnavigationBarから戻るとタイマーが作動したままになってしまうのです。
それとは別に設置したボタンなら、unwindSegueに対してprepareで処理できるのですが、このボタンの場合そのようなprepare処理は出来ないのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> navigationBarのbackButtonで戻った時にアクションを起こす方法

という質問の答えであれば、
[ViewControllerで戻るボタンのタップを検知する](http://qiita.com/yimajo/items/d9409d83fecf9875061d)の記事にある方法を試してみてはどうでしょうか。

記事はObjective-CなのでSwiftで一番ラクな方法を書くと下記のようになるかと思います。

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    if isMovingFromParentViewController() {
        // [戻る]ボタンを押された事がわかるのでここにTimerを止める処理
    }
}
```

Comment: yimajoさん
ご返答ありがとうございます！
そして返信が遅れて申し訳ありません。

viewDidLoad以外にも便利な方法があったのですね。
さっそく使わせていただきます。
ありがとうございました！